# Apache 2.4: How to allow access to a whole directory except a subdirectory in it

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I tried this in httpd.conf but it doesn't work, I still gives me access to the subfolder "report".

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/report">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need Allow or Deny in the Directory.

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/report">
    Allow from None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

More details in the Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work in Apache 2.4, this is for Apache 2.2. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html. I tried anyway just in case I get some luck but It didn't work.

Comment: In apache2.4 the default behavior is to block, so i think you dont need to type nothing....... try a require ip 127.0.0.1 in htdocs/report and see what happen.